# Desktop is all blurred! Help!

Tags: desktop-environments, desktop-background

I'm in desperate need of help.  I have no idea why my desktop is getting all blurred when I move things around on the screen or move between screens, minimize things, or highlight icons on the desktop.

I am running 12.04 Ubuntu.  This started happening after I restarted after running out of battery.

Thanks!!!!!!

[image]

Comment: What is your machine? Seems to be a delay due to GPU being too busy.

Comment: same problem, did you find any solution?